# Add extra items in list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this kind of list:

```
a = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana']
```

and from this I build another list of tuples using a simple *list comprehension*:

```
b = [(key, key.upper()) for key in a]
```

The result is something like this:

```
b = [('orange', 'ORANGE'), ('apple', 'APPLE'), ('banana', 'BANANA')]
```

Now I need to insert another tuple at the beginning (or at the end for example) of the newly generated `b` list: `('---', None)`.

The two easy solutions would be:

```
# Solution 1
b = [('---', None)] + b

# Solution 2 
b.insert(0, ('---', None))
```

**Question:**
Is there a way to accomplish the same thing directly from the list comprehension construct?
Can something like this (pseudocode) could be possible in python?

```
b = [('---', None), (key, key.upper()) for key in a]
```

Comment: `b = [('---', None)] + [(key, key.upper()) for key in a]` ??

Comment: `[('---', None), *((key, key.upper()) for key in a)]`?

Comment: @meissner_ `append()` and `extend()` do not return the `list`s they operate on.

Comment: `The two easy solutions would be:` - just select one of them. Python is for readability, not for "make everything with list comprehensions"

Comment: @soon yes, but what if those lists are huge? The two 'easy' solution I've mentioned probably are not so efficient? I should have probably mentioned also the efficiency requirements in the question

Comment: @Leonardo, Have you *tested* the performance of both methods, and that this is a bottleneck. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: My question is more theoretic than practical, I'm here for learning. I might one day encounter that bottleneck..or maybe not :)

Comment: I do not think so. Both list comprehension and element insertion takes O(N). How large is your list?

Comment: Could the people down-voting this leave a comment, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, by using generator comprehensions:

```
b = [('---', None), *((key, key.upper()) for key in a)]
```

Instead of using a generator comprehension, you *could* also use a list comprehension. The benefit of using generator comprehensions is that they don't create a new list, but hand out items one by one. If your list (`a`) is big, that can make an impact on memory use and/or performance.

Using the asterisk (the "splat operator") to unpack such a sequence is [PEP 448 — Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/). It allows you to use the `*` not just in function calls, but in list, generator, and set comprehensions (the same applying to `**` and dictionary comprehensions).

Comment: Thanks, do you mind very shortly explaining how generator comprehensions work/compare wrt list comprehensions, it's the first time I'm hearing of it

Comment: @Leonardo Sure, I tried to clarify the benefits in an edit.

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand exactly the `*`. I guess being outside of a function call it doesn't identifies  `*args` but it's more of *unpacking* operator?

Comment: It basically yields a sequence of the elements in the iterable to which it is applied.

Comment: @Leonardo Yes, that's [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 4):

**Premature optimization is the root of all evil**

The operation you have identified is most likely *not* your bottleneck. Using a clever list comprehension which allows you to use one expression does not solve a problem relating to performance. Below is a demonstration with 3mio items in your list.

If you need to *repeatedly* add items to your list to the left, I recommend you use `collections.deque`. Note that `deque` has O(1) complexity for `appendleft` while lists have O(n) performance for `insert(0, value)`.

```
from collections import deque

a = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana']*1000000

def l3v(a):
    return [('---', None), *((key, key.upper()) for key in a)]

def jpp(a):
    b = deque([(key, key.upper()) for key in a])
    b.appendleft(('---', None))
    return list(b)

def original(a):
    return [('---', None)] + [(key, key.upper()) for key in a]

def original2(a):
    b = [(key, key.upper()) for key in a]
    b.insert(0, ('---', None))
    return b

%timeit l3v(a)        # 1.35 s per loop
%timeit jpp(a)        # 1.23 s per loop
%timeit original(a)   # 1.17 s per loop
%timeit original2(a)  # 1.14 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Try an if else with the list comprehension. Like below

```
b = [(a[i],a[i].upper()) if i < len(a) else ('---',None)  for i in range(len(a)+1)]
```

Hope it helps.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This code is rather too non-obvious for my taste, but I admit this is a matter of taste. Rather more seriously, it appears to put the extra element at the wrong end of the list.

Comment: Also, it's rather wasteful to do that `if` test on _every_ item in `a`. (And in general, it's more usual in Python to directly iterate over containers, rather than indirect iteration via an index. If you really need the index as well as the item use `enumerate`).